# Java Prime Numbers

Tags: java, primes

I am trying to make a prime number list. I have coded it, but it only tells me that the prime numbers of 1 - 100 is 1. I am not sure why that is happening. I also want to make a JFrame for it.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProgrammingAssignment7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        //DECLARE VARIABLES

        int x = 1;
        int i = 1;
        int iNumber = 1;
        boolean bNotPrime = false;
        boolean bIsPrime = true;
        int iNumberToTest;
        int iPrimeCheck;
        int iCounter;
        int iResult = 1;
        int iFact = 1;
        int iLimit = 100;
        String OutputStr = null;

        System.out.println("Prime numbers between 1 and " + iLimit);

        //loop through the numbers one by one
        for(i=1; i < 100; i++) {
            bIsPrime = true;

            //check to see if the number is prime
            for(int j = 2; j < i ; j++) {
                if(i % j == 0) {
                    bIsPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // print the number
        if(bIsPrime) {
            OutputStr = "The Prime Numbers of 1 - 100 are: " + i + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, OutputStr, "PRIME NUMBERS", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        //System.out.print(i + "\n" );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to a minimal example and remove especially the commented lines from the code.

Comment: i is an int it can hold only one number. If you want a Collection of numbers then you have to create a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) or an [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 5):

You are calling system.exit(0) in your for loop. So that it will terminate the program after the first iteration. Remove that line and then try to run program. It will give you correct results.

Comment: +1. (Note to OP: proper indentation and other formatting would have made this obvious!)

Answer (score 1):

Besides fixing your code you should also fix your algorithm. You are using an algorithm called trial division, which will be uncomfortably slow as your limit increases. Instead, you should use an algorithm called the Sieve of Eratosthenes, invented over two thousand years ago and still widely used today. Here is pseudocode for a simple version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes; I'll leave it to you to translate to Java:

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n step 1
        if sieve[p]
           output p
           for i from p * p to n step p
               sieve[i] := False
```

Eratosthenes' algorithm begins by making a list of numbers form 2 to the maximum desired prime *n*, then enters an iterative phase. At each step, the smallest uncrossed number that hasn't yet been considered is identified, and all multiples of that number, starting from its square, are crossed out; this is repeated until no uncrossed numbers remain unconsidered. All the numbers that remain uncrossed are prime. The inner loop starts at `p * p` because any smaller composites must have already been crossed out by smaller primes.

For example, to find the primes less than thirty, first report that 2 is prime and cross out 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26 and 28. Then 3 is uncrossed, so report it as prime and cross out 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, and 27. Since 4 has been crossed out, the next uncrossed number is 5, so report it as prime and cross out 25. Finally, since 7 * 7 is greater than 30, the inner loop stops executing and the outer loop collects the rest of the primes: 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 and 29.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend an [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, which among other things provides an optimized version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, it is enough to iterate to the SQRT(N) instead of N. It can reduces a runtime a bit.

```
for(int j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(i) ; j++) {

}
```

Comment: Your code will reevaluate `Math.sqrt(i)` on each iteration, which is a fairly expensive computation; if performance is at all a concern, you should use `j * j <= i` instead. (Also, you only need to consider prime values of `j`, so it's better to use a sieve of Eratosthenes.)

Comment: ok, I took out the system.exit(0). Now, i have to click through the loop. I was hoping all the primes would be listed all at once.

Comment: ruakh, it doesn't reevaluate Math.sqrt(i) at each iteration since it will be optimized by compilder and calculated only once (before loop), instead of i * i, that the compiler should calculate at each iteration.

Comment: @VladimirKostyukov: `[citation needed]`. How does the compiler know that it can optimize it away? (How does it know whether `Math.sqrt` is a pure function?)

Comment: @ruakh, I see what mean. To make sure that it will be calculated only once - we can extract it from the loop into the variable. But, anyway, I belive it will be optimized.

Comment: You have to use "j <= Math..." to make it work for 4 and 9!

Answer (score 0):

Smart algorithm for writing out prime numbers from 1-100 (and also 1- [how many you want] - if you change *100* for another number). Prime numbers can be divisible only by two numbers: 1 and itself, so *k* have to be equals or less than 2.

```
for (int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        int k = 0;
        for (int j=1; j<=i; j++ ) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        if (k <= 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```